# Making inferences from linear regression

Tags: regression

In general, what valid inferences/descriptions can be made from regression model beta coefficients? Do they just need to be considered on a per unit basis with the input variable units or is there more complexity to it? Are there valid techniques that can be used to show the relative importance of each independent variable?

Answer (score 1):

You are right to point out the role a unit of measure plays in the coefficient magnitude. Regression users sometime talk about *effect size*. I sometimes use the product of beta (coefficient) and the standard deviation of the variable to gauge the economic significance of the variable. It is not an ideal measure by any means but it gives me an idea of importance.